# How to make different letters same height in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, text, lettering

[image: photoshop text line height]

Looking to find a way to make rounded letters and straight letters same height in Photoshop CC without manually doing so letter by letter. I'm looking for a quickest solution in PS.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do that? They are like that for good reason.

Comment: This is the way most fonts are made. I might be wrong, but there is no button you can click to achieve this. Your only option could be manual scaling.

Answer (score -1):

Hi please mention the font you have used.

Also these fonts have been created in a particular type.

As per my knowledge there is no easier way. You will have to do it manually.

However here is the tutorial of how you can adjust the height.

1. Write your text.
2. Select both the letter 'F'. Then change the font size according to the height of the letter 'O'

[image]
[image]